# Pushforward of projection map exact?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, exact-sequence

Let
$$0\to F \to G \to H\to 0$$
be a short exact sequence of coherent sheaves on the product spaces $X\times Y$, and $p$ be the projection to $X$. Is it true that
$$0\to p_*F \to p_*G \to p_*H\to 0$$
is still exact?

Comment: No (even when $X$ is the spectrum of your base field).

Comment: @Sasha Is it true for some special case like $F,G,H$ are line bundles and $X,Y$ are projective spaces?

Comment: One case this is true is when $Y$ is affine. If $Y$ is not affine, in general, this is false.

Comment: @UserX: $F$, $G$, and $H$ cannot be line bundles at the same time. A sufficient condition for the exactness is $R^1p_*F = 0$. This holds true, for instance, when $F$ is a sum of tensor products of line bundles pulled back from $X$ and $Y$, and $Y$ is a projective space of dimension $\ge 2$.

Comment: @Sasha Yeah this is enough for my case. Thx! You can post it as an answer if you want.

Comment: @Mohan hello! do you have any reference/argument that says this is indeed true for $Y$ affine? thx

Comment: Most standard texts dealing with cohomology will prove that for an affine morphism $p:A\to B$, $p_*$ is exact.